# Proper way to shutdown Apache httpcomponents blocking HTTP server

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I have application with Apache HttpComponents 4.4.1 **synchronous server**, which runs several HTTP "services", for each of them I start HTTP server on different port. When the user decides to stop the service, I shut down HTTP server running on this port with this code:

```
org.apache.http.impl.bootstrap.HttpServer server;
....

public void stopServer(){
    server.shutdown(42, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
}
```

I have the following problem on Linux: If there are Keep-alive connections opened (there is no request processing), these sockets are not closed. Only ServerSocket is closed:

```
netstat -aon | grep 58276
TCP    127.0.0.1:50658        127.0.0.1:58276        ESTABLISHED     18012
TCP    127.0.0.1:58276        127.0.0.1:50658        ESTABLISHED     18012
```

In attempt to start again HTTP server on the same port a BindingException is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:521)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:414)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:326)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:192)
at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:170)
at org.apache.http.impl.bootstrap.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:116)
```

On Windows the behavior is the same , however there is no BindingException and the server starts process requests without any problems.

Comment: Could you please put together a test case reproducing the issue and raise a JIRA at https://issues.apache.org/jira/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCORE-420
oleg has already proposed a fix. I will update this when it is released officially.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that connection is not closed. The HTTP specification does not specify how long a persistent connection should be kept alive.

From [documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html):

> Some HTTP servers use a non-standard `Keep-Alive` header to
>   communicate to the client the period of time in seconds they intend to
>   keep the connection alive on the server side. `HttpClient` makes use
>   of this information if available. If the `Keep-Alive` header is not
>   present in the response, `HttpClient` assumes the connection can be
>   kept alive indefinitely.

So they advise to create your `KeepAliveStrategy` in order to terminate those connections after certain time:

```
ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy myStrategy = new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {

    public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
        // Honor 'keep-alive' header
        HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator(
                response.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            HeaderElement he = it.nextElement();
            String param = he.getName();
            String value = he.getValue();
            if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase("timeout")) {
                try {
                    return Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
                } catch(NumberFormatException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
        HttpHost target = (HttpHost) context.getAttribute(
                HttpClientContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);
        if ("www.naughty-server.com".equalsIgnoreCase(target.getHostName())) {
            // Keep alive for 5 seconds only
            return 5 * 1000;
        } else {
            // otherwise keep alive for 30 seconds
            return 30 * 1000;
        }
    }

};
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setKeepAliveStrategy(myStrategy)
        .build();
```

Comment: I'm using http-components **server**. My code runs server side. I don't know what clients will connect to my server.